# How to write multi-line constraint for ParentId/HierarchyId

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called Items with these three fields:

- Id (int)
- ParentId(int)
- NodeId (HierarchyId)

  ```
  Id  NodeId  ParentId
  2   /       NULL
  3   /120/1/ 1520
  4   /1/     2
  ```

`ParentId` and `NodeId` are basically duplicates as they both point to the parent. In the future, `ParentId` will be dropped in favor of the `HierarchyId`.

However, in the meantime, I need to ensure that they stay in sync, so I need to write a constraint to ensure this:

```
declare @id int = 4

DECLARE @result int = 0, @parentNodeId1 HierarchyId,@parentNodeId2 HierarchyId, @parentId int; 


Select @parentNodeId1 = NodeId.GetAncestor(1), @parentId = parentId from Items where id = @id;

Select @parentNodeId2 = NodeId from Items where Id = @parentId;

if @parentNodeId1 = @parentNodeId2
Select @result = 1;
```

How do I write this as a constraint?

**Update**

I tried Damiens solution as suggested.  It works to enforce the multi-column integrity on existing data. However, the NodeId can change from left to right in the hierarchy. For example a NodeId of `/1/` can change to `/3/`. It's parent has not changed (the parent is `/`), so really the Foreign Key has not been in-validated. And this works for items with no children.

However, if an item has children, and the NodeId is changed, the database engine sees it as a violation of the Foreign Key and throws an error.

See this DB Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=44637c2bbed80b8db3f305933798cdad

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [NodeId] [hierarchyid] NOT NULL,
    [_ParentNodeId]  AS ([NodeId].[GetAncestor]((1))) PERSISTED,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_People] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [NodeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[People] ([Id], [ParentId], [NodeId]) VALUES (1, NULL, N'/')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[People] ([Id], [ParentId], [NodeId]) VALUES (2, 1, N'/2/')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[People] ([Id], [ParentId], [NodeId]) VALUES (3, 1, N'/3/')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[People] ([Id], [ParentId], [NodeId]) VALUES (4, 2, N'/2/1/')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[People] ([Id], [ParentId], [NodeId]) VALUES (5, 4, N'/2/1/1.1/')
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[People]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_People_Parent] FOREIGN KEY([ParentId], [_ParentNodeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[People] ([Id], [NodeId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[People] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_People_Parent]
GO

Update People set NodeId = N'/2/1/2/' where Id = 5--Works


Update People set NodeId = N'/2/2/' where Id = 4 --Error
```

Comment: In this data, what's the parent of record with `id = 3` - by the int column it is 1520, but by the hierarchy id it should be `120`, right?

Comment: By HierarchyId, the parent would be the record with a NodeId of '/120/', which is different from an Id of 120 (it is not shown in the sample data.)

Comment: As an aside, my personal preference is to keep the ParentID around and use the IDs in your hierarchy path. For example, rather than having `/120/1/` as the path for ID=3, you'd have '/2/4/`. That way, if something ever gets messed up with the hierarchyid, it can be regenerated.

Comment: @BenThul, Totally agree on keeping ParentId around so that the HierarchyId can be regenerated. I have had to do that a few times.

Answer (score 2):

If we can add another column, a foreign key constraint can enforce this:

```
create table T(
    Id int not null,
    NodeId hierarchyid,
    ParentId int,
    _ParentNodeId as NodeId.GetAncestor(1) persisted,
    constraint PK_T primary key (Id,NodeId),
    constraint FK_T_Parent foreign key (ParentId,_ParentNodeId) references T (Id,NodeId)
)
```

(I'm using the PK as the FK target, but any unique constraint will do if, say, `Id` is the current PK and you want to keep that)

I've prefixed the new column name with `_`. That's my convention for "I'm adding this column for **my** purposes in enforcing integrity. I don't expect anybody else to ever even look in it".